# C# TweetSharp WCF service fails to generate TwitterMention

Tags: c#, wcf, tweetsharp

So using VS2010 (or SVCUTIL.EXE) to created a WCF class, it does not generate the TwitterMention part of the TwitterStatus or TwitterStatus.TwitterEntities.

For example, I cannot access TwitterStatus.Entities.Mentions or any properties if I wanted to create a TwitterMention instance.

So here is what it generates (see TwitterEntities is fine) and the lack of code might be why:

So anyone got any ideas how I can get a WCF proxy class that generates correctly involving the TwitterMention class?

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TwitterEntities", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TweetSharp")]
public partial class TwitterEntities : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TwitterMention", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TweetSharp")]
public partial class TwitterMention : TweetSharp.TwitterEntity
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem disappeared when checking out and building TweetSharp from source. It seems to have been solved.